# Perfil de empleado con foto php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

He creado una pagina para crear el perfil de un empleado, ya eso carga bien a la BD e inclusive pude agregar una foto, la sube bien a un folder que le designe  y todo va bien.

El problema es que se me ocurrió que cuando se esta creando el perfil y se seleccione la imagen se puede ver a la par del formulario de los datos... pero el problema es que cuando selecciono la imagen y esta se previsualiza de una vez guardan los datos... esto sin darle el boton de enviar...

**El formulario lo tengo así**

```
 <form id="imageform" class="form-horizontal center-block" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Codigo -->    
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label titulos1">Código</label>
                  <div class=" col-sm-3 input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="codigo" class="form-control" placeholder="Código" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Nombre Completo -->   
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nombre Completo</label>
                  <div class=" col-sm-6 input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" name="nombres" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Completo" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Correo Electrónico -->    
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                    <div class=" col-sm-6 input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" name="lugar_nacimiento" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Teléfono -->  
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Teléfono / Celular</label>
                    <div class=" col-sm-6 input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono / Celular" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"> <!-- Fecha de nacimiento -->   
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>

        </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"> 
                Subir imganes:                     
                 <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">              

                <div id='preview'>
                    <!--<img class="center-block img-thumbnail" src="imges/default.png" width="300" height="300"> -->
                </div>                 

                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Guardar datos">                            
                            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </form>
```

**Este es el javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {             
            $('#fileToUpload').live('change', function()            { 
                       $("#preview").html('');
                $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Cargando...."/>');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
            }).submit();

            });
        }); 
</script>
```

**Y este es el PHP**

```
$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
/*if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){*/
    echo "SI ENTRO 1 IF!!!";
    $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
    /*echo "Este es el nombre del archivo ".$name."<br><br>";*/
    if(strlen($name)){
        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)){
            if($size<(1024*1024)){
                $actual_image_name = $name;
                $tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
                /*echo "Este es el archivo : ". $tmp."<br><br>";*/
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)){
                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$name."' class='preview2 center-block img-thumbnail' width='300' height='300'>";

                    /*echo "Este es el archivo : ". $actual_image_name."<br><br>";*/
                }else
                    echo "Error al cargar la imágen";
                }
            else
                echo "La imagen pesa más de 1 mege";                    
            }
            else
                echo "Formato de imagen incorrecto";    
        }           
    else
        echo "Favor seleccionar imagen";
    /*exit;*/
/*}*/
```

Con la respuesta de Camilo, cambié el codigo pero no me sirve.. estoes lo qu puse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Agregar Usuario

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
     $("#fileToUpload").change(function(){
  var imagen = $(this)[0].files[0];

  var reader  = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(imagen);

  reader.onload = function(){
    var dataURL = reader.result;

    $("#preview").html('<img class="center-block img-thumbnail" src="'+ dataURL +'" width="300" height="300">');
  }
});
</script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">           
        <form class="form-horizontal center-block" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">              
            <div id="preview">

            </div>                
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Guardar datos">                            
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
            </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código del javascript y del php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en este código:

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    target: '#preview'
}).submit();
```

En ese código estás haciendo el `submit` para el formulario. Si lo que quieres es hacer un preview de la imagen te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```js
$("#fileToUpload").change(function(){
  var imagen = $(this)[0].files[0];
  
  var reader  = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(imagen);
  
  reader.onload = function(){
    var dataURL = reader.result;
    
    $("#preview").html('<img class="center-block img-thumbnail" src="'+ dataURL +'" width="300" height="300">');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">              
<div id='preview'>
    
</div>
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos es convertir la imagen a formato base64 para poder visualizarla inmediatamente sin alterar el objeto de imagen que se envía al PHP.

Comment: Hola Camilo, gracias por la respuesta... vieras que no logro que me funcione. puse esto

Comment: <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" >
         $("#fileToUpload").change(function(){
      var imagen = $(this)[0].files[0];
      
      var reader  = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(imagen);
      
      reader.onload = function(){
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        
        $("#preview").html('<img class="center-block img-thumbnail" src="'+ dataURL +'" width="300" height="300">');
      }
    });
    </script>   </head>

Comment: <pre>
<body>   
            <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
              <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">              
                <div id="preview">                    
                </div>                
                 
                </form>

</body>
</pre>

Comment: Creo que es por que estas colocando el código en el <head>, colócalo al final del <body>

Comment: Hola Camil.... lo cambié como mencionaste y ta me funciono de lo mejor, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionara @Joe es importante que sepas que no te funcionaba en el <head> por que estabas accediendo a los elementos antes de que estos existieran en el DOM...otra solución que se podía hacer era encerrar todo tu código en un evento ready asignado al document: $(document).ready(function(){
    // código aquí
});